# How to send chosen radio button value to modal in asp.net core razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. In my razor i have written some code like below for making some radio buttons and depending to which radio button user chose, if user clicks the following div, it should show related data on a modal.

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal" data-id="">
                    <div class="w3-container w3-padding-16" style="color:white; background-color:#2fc86c;">
                       
                        <div class="">
                            <h3>@ViewBag.TotalApiCount</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-clear"></div>
                        <h5>Total API count</h5>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>


<form method="post" style="height: 4rem;">
    <div class="container" style="width: 35rem;height:3rem;margin-top: 1.5rem;">
        <h4 style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 3rem;">Report</h4>

        @foreach (var year in Model.Years)
        {
            if (Model.IsFirst)
            {
                if (year == "1399")
                {
                    <input type="radio" asp-for="Year" value="@year" checked="checked" style="margin-right: 2rem;" />

                    <p class="d-inline-block">@year</p>

                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="radio" asp-for="Year" value="@year" style="margin-right: 2rem;" />

                    <p class="d-inline-block">@year</p>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="radio" asp-for="Year" value="@year" style="margin-right: 2rem;" />

                <p class="d-inline-block">@year</p>
            }


        }
      
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="@Model.Year" />


        <input type="submit" value="submit" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-right: 3rem;" />
    </div>
</form>



    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>*@
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       
                        <div id="result">
                            <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr id="headerrow">
                                        <th>
                                           service name
                                        </th>
                                     
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="exitbutton" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">exit</button>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section scripts{
        <script>
        @{
            if (ViewBag.ModalState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ModalState = "hide";
            }
        }
        $('#exampleModal').modal('@ViewBag.ModalState');

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

// Here year is null!

            var year = $("#hiddenInput").val();

            $.get('@Url.Action("ProducedAPIDetails", "Home")/'+ year , function (data) {



                $.each(data, function (index, value) {



                    var markup = "<tr><td>" + value.apiName +"</td></tr>";
                  
                    $("#classTable").append(markup);
               })

            });

        });
        </script>
    }
```

Here is the action in Home controller that send data to modal pop up:

```
public IList<ApiApplicantDTO> ProducedAPIDetails(string year)
{

    List<ApiApplicantDTO> al = new List<ApiApplicantDTO>();

    ApiApplicantDTO apDTO;



    var TotalApiCount = somequery.Select(x => new
    {
        ApiName = x.Name,
    }).ToList();

    if (year == "total")
    {
        TotalApiCount =somequery.Where(x => x.LastStatus == "1").Select(x => new
        {
            ApName = x.Name,
        }).ToList();
    }

    foreach (var index in TotalApiCount)
    {
        apDTO = new ApApplicantDTO();

        apDTO.apName = index.ApName;
        
        al.Add(apDTO);
    }
    
    return al;
}
```

Here is my model properties for radio button:

```
public string Year { get; set; }

public string[] Years = new[] { "2020", "2019", "total" };
```

My problem is, I can't send the chosen radio button value to my modal and then send it to its related action in controller. I appreciate of any help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the url format of $.ajax, the way to get the value of action is through API. You need to delete the , because these elements do not use form elements and the button in the  will affect the custom click event.
Here is the modal that has been modified.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            @*<form >  *@
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="result">
                    <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>

                            <tr id="headerrow">
                                <th>
                                    service name
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="exitbutton" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">exit</button>
                <button id="subyear" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
            </div>
            @*</form>*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script. It get the data from action ProducedAPIDetails.

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        @{
            if (ViewBag.ModalState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ModalState = "hide";
            }
        }
        
        $('#exampleModal').modal('@ViewBag.ModalState');

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

//This year must be assigned initial value.
            var year = $("#hiddenInput").val();
            $.get('@Url.Action("ProducedAPIDetails", "Home")/' + year, function (data) {

                    $("#classTable").empty()
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    var markup = "<tr><td>" + value.apiName +"</td></tr>";

                    $("#classTable").append(markup);
                })
                var years = document.getElementsByName('Year')
                $.each(years, function (index, y) {
                    if (y.checked) {
                        $("#classTable").append('<tr><td id="yearmoal">' + y.value + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                })
                
            });
           

        });
        $('#subyear').click(function () {
            location.href = '/home/index/' + $('#yearmoal').text()
        })
    </script>
}
```

Here is the action method.

```
[Route("index/{year}")]
        public IActionResult Index(string year)
        {
            return Json(year);
        }
        [Route("produce")]
        public IActionResult produce()
        {
//The hide year should be assigned here.
            var apDTO = new ApiApplicantDTO
            {
                Year = "2020"
            };
            return View(apDTO);
        }
        [Route("ProducedAPIDetails/{year}")]
        public IList<ApiApplicantDTO> ProducedAPIDetails(string year)
        {

            List<ApiApplicantDTO> al = new List<ApiApplicantDTO>();

            ApiApplicantDTO apDTO;
//Here is the simulated data.
            al = new List<ApiApplicantDTO>
            {
                new ApiApplicantDTO{apiName="apiName1"},
                new ApiApplicantDTO{apiName="apiName2"},
            };
            
            return al;
        }
    }
```

Here is the model.

```
public class ApiApplicantDTO
    {
        public string apiName { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public string[] Years = new[] { "2020", "2019", "total" };
       //…
    }
```

result:
[image]